# TypeError: can only concaenate list (not "str") to list but i've included type checks

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, typeerror

so i am building a gui which takes in three different csv files combines, compares, and searches them for given values and fields. Got an interesting problem i just can't figure out. Located where it's happening no further luck. This function is called later in the code in another func
def policy_match(policy, var):

```
json_sort = json.loads(policy)
resource_holder = []
for info in json_sort["Statement"]:
    for key, value in info.items():
        if(key == "Resource"):
            if(type(value) is list):
                resource_holder.extend(value)
            elif(type(value) is str):
                resource_holder = resource_holder + (value)
for resource in resource_holder:
    if var in resource:
        has_resource = True
        break
return has_resource
```

error happens in the elif loop on line resource_holder = resource holder + value 
returns TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list. Any ideas?

Comment: you're trying to add a list and a string. the error message is pretty explicit in that you can't do that. What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator is overloaded and represents list concatenation when one of the operands is a list. As the error says, if the other operand is not a list, you can't concatenate it. Instead, you should be using the `append` method. Replace `resource_holder = resource_holder + (value)` with `resource_holder.append(value)` and it should work fine.